# How do you get the user role of the currently logged in user in Ckan?

Tags: python, ckan

I want to know about user role in ckan , we can use **userobj.sysadmin** for admin but what I want is to know about all users ,

**e.g.,**  **userobj.sysadmin** returns True for admin and false for others  so I can,t differentiate between editor and member , So is their any way to know about editor or member , I want this in dataset creation not in organisation . So that I can provide permission to users as I want.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [roles_show](https://ckan.readthedocs.org/en/ckan-2.0/ckan.logic.action.get.html#ckan.logic.action.get.roles_show) action. An [Example](http://demo.ckan.org/api/action/roles_show?user=dominik&domain_object=geojson-demo-for-blog).